# how to avoid memory leaks caused by dijits?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, dojo

I'm new to dojo and currently having some problems with significant memory leaks. Since I read that the JavaScript garbage collector might have problems with dijits that haven't been destroyed, I'm trying to take care of that, but haven't been too successful.

So first I'm trying to get rid of all widgets, when the page is being left:

```
dojo.addOnWindowUnload(function(){
    dijit.registry.forEach(function(widget){
        widget.destroy();
    });
});
```

This seems to help a bit, but not as much as I would have expected. So at certain stages I call:

```
dojo.forEach(dijit.findWidgets(node), function(widget){
    widget.destroyRecursive();
});
```

But I'm still having memory leaks pretty sure caused by dijits somehow. Are there any general tips and best practices how to get rid of such? Or should the calls above be able to take care of everything and I have to look somewhere else for the leaks? Well, I know it's a pretty general question, but I hope you can give me some hints anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: only Firefox/OSx atm, Safari/OSx seems to behave much better. Haven't tested others yet.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do this yourself - see http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/tags/release-1.5.0/dijit/_base/manager.js#L293.

If you're having memory leaks once you've destroyed the page or tab then it's most likely a bug in Dijit. Please make a minimal test case and submit a ticket to trac, or paste it here and I'll take a look and/or pass it over to someone who might be able to help.